# Cannot create new entry with extended model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, dependency-injection

I am trying to create an app which will contain multiple user roles, let's say 'admin' and 'client'.
There is 'users' table which contains 'entity_type_id': 1 - admin, 2 - client.

App\Models\User class:

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\EAV\BaseModel; 
use App\Models\Resources\EAV\EntityTypeResource;

class User extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model { 
    protected $fillable = [ 'entity_type_id', 'email', 'password', 'remember_token' ];
    protected $entityType;
    protected $entityTypeId;
    private $entityTypeResource;
    
    public function __construct(
        EntityTypeResource $entityTypeResource
    ) {
        $this->entityTypeResource = $entityTypeResource;
    }
    
    protected function getEntityType() {
        if ($this->entityType) return $this->entityType;
    
        return $this->entityTypeResource->loadByCode($this->entityTypeCode);
    }
    
    public function getEntityTypeId() {
        if ($this->entityTypeId) return $this->entityTypeId;
    
        return $this->getEntityType()->id;
    }
}
```

App\Models\UserTypes\Admin class:

```
<?php 
namespace App\Models\UserTypes;

use App\Models\User;

class Admin extends User { 
    protected $entityTypeCode = 'admin';
    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();
    
        static::addGlobalScope(function ($query) {
            $query->where('entity_type_id', 1);
        });
    }
}
```

Now, when I call:

```
Route::get('test/model', function (
    App\Models\UserTypes\Admin $admin
) {
    var_dump($admin::first());
});
```

I get this error: **Too few arguments to function App\Models\User::__construct(), 0 passed in...**

As far as I know, Laravel should resolve dependency by itself in this case, what am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not recommended to override the model constructor with different arguments. I think laravel just expects the default constructor for all models.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel: Too few arguments to function when I want to update my database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71889544/laravel-too-few-arguments-to-function-when-i-want-to-update-my-database)

Comment: @TrevorV Nope, I have problem with model, not route or controller.

Comment: Hmm, how should dependency injection work then? @apokryfos

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what does the constructor of your `User` model look like?

Comment: Thanks :D You can see the constructor of the User model in the question itself. @lagbox

Comment: you can't override the signature of the constructor that way... it has to at the least have the same first argument as the base `Model`, every argument has to be optional as you are not the one creating new instances of the Model at most times ... in most places the models are not resolved from the container, they are `new`ed up

Comment: @lagbox Okay, but the following code is working fine:
Route::get('test/model', function (
    App\Models\User$user
) {
    var_dump($user->getEntityType());
});

Which means that dependency is actually resolving this way.

Comment: because that is method injection which is resolving it from the container, other places they are not, the Model itself does not create instance of itself via the container, it uses `new` .. so any static method on the Model that would return an instance does not use the container ... so if you want to use it as an Eloquent Model you can't be doing this .... `User::first();` will be broken, `User::newInstance()` broken .... there are tons of places that `new` is called

Comment: Do you know how to write dependency in the way that is as close as in my question? To be precise, without repeating all dependecies every time that I need to call User or Admin class.

Comment: Your code looks like it's trying to shove a repository pattern in your model (which in Laravel is an active record pattern). If you do prefer the repository over active record then I would recommend implementing your repositories and all associated logic outside the model and keep the model as plain and simple data object